# Read entity reference node field

Tags: 8, views, entities

I have a referenced entity named - field_cp_level2_ref_level3. This field belongs to level3 content type. when I dump the $entity, I see the field as below:

```
entity:node:level3::field_cp_level2_ref_level3 => Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList (9) Depth Limit
```

how to read the value of this field? I tried to read the value as below:

```
$var =  $entity->$node->field_cp_level2_ref_level3->value;
```

dpm($var) returns null. how to read this field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$entity->field_x->referencedEntities();` which will return an array of referenced entity objects

Comment: doing so, throws the below error - "Error: Call to a member function referencedEntities() on null "

Comment: That suggests there's nothing in your field. Maybe wrap it in an is null check.